# Objects keep disappearing over long distances

Tags: rendering

If I make an object like a cloud and put it far away, it disappears in the render. Is there any tricks to fix this?

Comment: Check the clipping distances

Answer (score 1):

In the properties panel (toggled by pressing "N") and under "View", increase the end clipping until it appears again.

[image]